# add_vat:127 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'delete'

Tags: javascript

Hello i have a problem with my js code. I get an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'delete'. I just don't understand what wrong could I do in making a function.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
             window.onload = function() 
             {
                 var id_count = 1;
                 var btn = document.getElementById("add_product");
                 btn.addEventListener("click", function()
                 {
                     id_count += 1;
                     document.getElementById("products_table").innerHTML +=
                     "<tr id='" + id_count +"'>\
                         <td>" + id_count +"</td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name' id='name" + id_count +"' placeholder='Jane Doe'></td>\
                         <td><input type='number' class='form-control' name='count' id='count" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_netto' id='price_netto" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td class='input-group'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='vat_rate' id='vat_rate" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'>\
                             <span class='input-group-addon'>%</span>\
                         </td>\
                         <td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price_brutto' id='price_brutto" + id_count +"' placeholder='jane.doe@example.com'></td>\
                         <td><button type='button' onclick='document.getElementById(" + id_count +").remove();' class='btn btn-alert'>Usuń</button></td>\
                     </tr>";
                 }, false);

                 function delete()
                 {

                 }
             }

        </script>
```

Comment: `delete` is a keyword, and in that context a keyword is not expected. Only in languages like Rust and VB you can escape keywords.

Comment: Oh thanks that solves my problem ^_^